# Сложности при корректировке переведённой с английского фразы

Tags: перевод

сложности при корректировке переведённой с английского фразы:
**Ах, я без ума от мужчин, которые получают от жизни всё, что хотят.**
(Ohhhh. I just adore men who can get what they want out of life.)

Мне кажется, сочетание "всё что хочет" применимо и без запятой. Напрашивается "вcего, чего хотят". Помогите переформулировать фразу без избыточных запятых. Может быть так:
"Ах, я без ума от мужчин, добивающихся в жизни всего, что хотят."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без запятой пишется придаточное предложение, состоящее из одного слова: Мне грустно, и не знаю почему. А "всё, что хочет" пишется с запятой, так как это обычное неполное придаточное предложение. Что касается Вашего намерения заменить слова "...которые получают от жизни всё, что хотят" на фразу "добивающихся в жизни всего, чего хотят", то, согласитесь, смысловая наполненность фразы меняется: получать от жизни всё можно без усилий (например, "золотая молодежь", отпрыски богатых или влиятельных родителей), а чтобы добиться в жизни всего,чего хочется, нужно приложить усилия, и немалые. Разница есть. И еще. Я не большой знаток английского языка, но, насколько позволяют мои познания, приведенная Вами фраза дословно переводится так: "...мужчин, которые могут получить все, что они хотят от жизни", поэтому "получают" и "могут получить" - это не одно и то же. Дополнение.Но дословность дословности рознь. Иногда "вольность" перевода может привести к искажению смысла фразы, изначально заложенного в первоисточнике. Я пытался в своем ответе показать это, но, видимо, не убедил Вас. Простите. А дословность, соглашусь, не всегда нужна. Хрестоматийный пример - перевод обожаемым мною М.Ю.Лермонтовым стихотворения Г.Гейне о сосне, которая страдает от любви к пальме. Чем не символ лесбийской любви!А все дело, оказывается, в том, что одно из названных деревьев употребляется в немецком языке с артиклем мужского рода, а другое - с женским родом (не помню точно, какое с каким артиклем)

Comment: Я обычно стараюсь уходить от "дословности". Здесь позволительно хотя бы не инвертировать смысл. "...мужчин, которые могут получить все, что они хотят от жизни" так простая девичья фраза на английском становится более сложной по строению при переводе, нужно бы оставить прежде всего простоту. 
Не является ли форма "всё, что хотят" недопустимой? Поправлю на "всего, чего хотят"

Comment: Виктору
приведенная Вами фраза дословно переводится так: "...мужчин, которые могут получить все, что они хотят от жизни", поэтому "получают" и "могут получить" - это не одно и то же. -- В англ. предл. настоящее, НЕ будущее время - могут получать, умеют получать, не могут получить.

Переводчик правит. США на пенсии. Дам уроки по Скайпу. Звони alex dihes.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы перевел так:

> Как же я обожаю мужчин, берущих от жизни свое!

Междометие "Ах!" - это что-то из XIX века, а "свое" - в одном из значений, это как раз то, что можно получить (получить все свое сполна).

Answer (score 0):

Дословный перевод:

Я просто обожаю мужчин, которые могут получить то, чего они хотят от жизни

Предлагаемый вариант перевода: Я просто обожаю мужчин, которые могут получить от жизни что хотят.

Оборот "что хотят" не обособляется, глагол "хотеть" может управлять как Р.п., та и В.п.

Answer (score 0):

I just adore men who can get what they want out of life.

Пословный пер.
Ах, я просто обожаю мужчин, которые могут получать, чего они хотят от жизни.

Литературн.
Ах, я просто обожаю мужчин, которые могут получать от жизни, чего они хотят. 
или
Ах, я просто обожаю мужчин, которые могут получать от жизни то, чего они хотят.

В твоём переводе: Ах, я без ума от мужчин, которые получают от жизни всё, что хотят зпт нужна. Она отделяет неполн. придат. предлож. 
Можно составить пример, где сочетание *всё что хочешь будет без зпт., но не в этом случае.

Перевод *без ума - далёк от смысла, было бы: I just (go) crazy of men... or go mad of men...